# Hard coded date working but not the passed parameter in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Framing my question better now.

I have created a query wherein I am passing from date and to date. The effective_date column check is added so that it should be between 
from_date and to_date. In case this effective_date does not have any value this condition should be checked as on "from_date" so that the query still
gives results with rest of the column details.

When I am passing the hard coded value :

```
AND To_char(ppa.effective_date(+), 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-11-02'
```

this is giving me the right result. But when I am using the below condition :

```
AND To_char(Nvl(ppa.effective_date(+), :p_from_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN To_char( Nvl(:p_from_date, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND To_char ( Nvl(:p_TO_date, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I am not getting the right results.

The overall query is :

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT PAPF.person_number, 
                            paam.assignment_number, 
                            pprd.payroll_relationship_number, 
                            payf.payroll_name, 
                            ppa.payroll_action_id action_number, 
                            ppa.action_type, 
                           to_char( ppa.effective_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')  effective_date, 
                            PCS.consolidation_set_name, 
                            name.first_name, 
                            name.last_name 
            FROM   pay_payroll_actions PPA, 
                   pay_payroll_rel_actions PPRA, 
                   pay_pay_relationships_dn pprd, 
                   per_all_people_f PAPF, 
                   per_all_assignments_m PAAM, 
                   per_assignment_status_types_vl pasv, 
                   pay_payroll_assignments ppasg, 
                   pay_assigned_payrolls_dn papd, 
                   pay_all_payrolls_f payf, 
                   pay_consolidation_sets pcs, 
                   pay_time_periods ptp, 
                   per_legislative_data_groups_vl ldg, 
                   pay_payroll_terms pt, 
                   per_person_names_f name 
            WHERE  1 = 1 
                   AND pt.payroll_relationship_id = pprd.payroll_relationship_id 
                   AND papd.payroll_term_id = pt.payroll_term_id 
                   AND ( action_type IN ( 'Q', 'R' ) 
                          OR action_type IS NULL ) 
                   AND papf.person_id = name.person_id 
                   AND name.name_type = 'GLOBAL' 
                   AND paam.person_id = papf.person_id 
                   AND pprd.person_id = papf.person_id 
                   AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM.effective_start_date AND 
                                       PAAM.effective_end_date 
                   AND PAAM.assignment_number NOT LIKE 'ET%' 
                   AND PAAM.assignment_type = 'E' 
                   AND paam.primary_flag = 'Y' 
                   AND pasv.assignment_status_type_id = 
                       paam.assignment_status_type_id 
                   --AND paam.assignment_status_type = 'ACTIVE' 
                   AND pasv.pay_system_status = 'P' 
                   AND ptp.payroll_id = payf.payroll_id 
                   AND ( finc > ptp.start_date 
                          OR finc IS NULL ) 
                   AND PTP.period_category = 'E' 
                   AND ppa.payroll_action_id(+) = ppra.payroll_action_id 
                   AND ppra.payroll_relationship_id(+) = 
                       pprd.payroll_relationship_id  
                   **AND To_char(Nvl(ppa.effective_date(+), :p_from_date), 
                       'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                       BETWEEN 
                       To_char( 
                       Nvl(:p_from_date, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND To_char ( 
                           Nvl(:p_TO_date, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')** 
            ORDER  BY pprd.payroll_relationship_number DESC 
           --95278  
           ) 
    WHERE 1=1
    and action_type IS NULL 
and person_number = '67373'
```

The result set in case effective_date is null should be like :

```
PERSON_NUMBER PAYROLL_NAME ACTION_TYPE EFFECTIVE_DATE CONSOLIDATION_SET_NAME ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_NUMBER ACTION_NUMBER
     67373       US Biweekly                            US_CONSOLIDATION_GROUP   E67373                  67373
```

The above query is returning if I pass the hardcode value. Th effective_date, action_type is in the same table. If in the passed p_from_date
and p_to_date the action_type is null, then the query should give the above result.

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't transform dates to strings and then compare them. Compare them directly.

Comment: I am passing the date and hence i need to pass in the same format

Comment: That shouldn't hinder you to convert the strings to a `date`s in the `WHERE` clause rather than the other way round.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Did you try to **1)** get the same error while joining only *two tables* (and not 14)? **2)** log the values that are passed as bind variables? Post it and you'll get help much easier;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `ppa.effective_date` is a `date`.  If so, you really want to compare dates, not strings.

To see what sort of invisible chaos happens when you compare strings, let's look at just one expression

```
To_char(Nvl(ppa.effective_date(+), :p_from_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

First, we have to evaluate the `nvl`.  In order to do that, however, we have to first convert `ppa.effective_date` to a string so that we're comparing the same data type.  Since it is an implicit conversion, we have to use the session's `nls_date_format`.  Not only does that mean that different sessions and users might experience different behavior, it means that someone looking at just the code won't know which behavior you're getting.  If you're using the default `nls_date_format`, `ppa.effective_date` would get converted to a string in the format "DD-MON-RR".  In that case, the `nvl` would return a string in a different format whether `effective_date` was `NULL` or not.  But maybe you've changed your session's `nls_date_format` to "YYYY-MM-DD" so that the `nvl` returns a string in the same format regardless of whether `effective_date` is NULL.

Once we're done with the `nvl`, we need to evaluate the `to_char`.  But `to_char` doesn't take a string, it just takes a date.  So we need to do another implicit conversion of the string from the `nvl` (which could be in different formats) to a `date` in order to pass it to `to_char`.  Best case, then, we're taking a string, implicitly casting it to a `date` using the session's `nls_date_format` in order to explicitly cast it back to a string using the provided "YYYY-MM-DD" format.  That might or might not work correctly depending on what you got back from the `nvl` and what your session's `nls_date_format` happens to be.

If you look at two expressions that are part of your `between` clause, you have a similar set of conversion issues.  And then your `between` uses string comparison semantics rather than date comparison semantics so if one of your three expressions returns an unexpected string, the comparison just silently doesn't do what you want rather than throwing an error.

Realistically, you want to compare dates.  So you want to cast your parameters to dates and compare them.  Something like this (assuming `:p_from_date` and `:p_to_date` are always strings in the format "yyyy-mm-dd")

```
AND nvl( ppa.effective_date(+), to_date( :p_from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) ) 
      BETWEEN nvl( to_date( :p_from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), trunc(sysdate) )
          AND nvl( to_date( :p_to_date,   'yyyy-mm-dd' ), trunc(sysdate) )
```

Since a `date` always has a day and a time component, I am guessing that you want to compare against `trunc(sysdate)` (today at midnight) rather than the current date and time.  You may want the upper bound to be 11:59:59 pm today in which case you'd have

```
AND nvl( ppa.effective_date(+), to_date( :p_from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) ) 
      BETWEEN nvl( to_date( :p_from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), trunc(sysdate) )
          AND nvl( to_date( :p_to_date,   'yyyy-mm-dd' ), trunc(sysdate+1) - interval '1' second )
```

Comment: to_date( :p_from_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) )  this is giving an incorrect  error - ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @Sree - OK.  Then `:p_from_date` is not a string in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` which explains much of the problem you're having.  What format is that string in?

Comment: i am using the bip tool, the p_from_date is date format and format is in "yyyy-MM-dd" form

Comment: @Sree - What do you mean by "bip tool"?  Is `:p_from_date` a `date` (in which case it does not have a format)?  Or a string (in which case it has a format)?